# openvpn exclude some web pages

Tags: openvpn, openwrt

I have OpenWrt with openvpn on it.
Some computers are excluded from openvpn traffic by `--set-mark` rules.

But now I need some more elastic solution. I am using VPN for web browsing, but some web pages need to be excluded from vpn i.e bank or online shops.

How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to introduce some proxy software like squid to do this. OpenVPN operates too far down the networking stack to be able to efficiently filter HTTP traffic.